# Heatmap chart is not showing properly for large data points

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I want to show the heatmap chart but for the large data points chart is not coming correctly. I have 36 categories [for now, it can be more] on `X-axis` and `Y-axis` and according to this, I have generated the heatmap chart.

Please refer this fiddle:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 30,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ["offer", "Brand Launch Sale", "Women's wear", "Brand", "Weekday bonanza offer", "Women's ddd", "Home fashion sae", "Women fff", "Fashion fiesta offer", "Fashion", "Weekday", "Fashion fies", "Local", "Home le", "Weekdayfff", "Women jena", "Week off", "Women's jewlly", "Brand Launch", "Local brand", "Fashion bazaa", "Women gadf", "Weekend look", "Home fashion avtar", "Weekend ohhh", "Week log", "Local phinomy", "Weekend dhamaka", "Fashionghanae", "Weekday dhamaka", "Womejnfv", "Brandrr Sale", "Demo", "defe", "Otherc", "c3"]
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ["offer", "Brand Launch Sale", "Women's wear", "Brand", "Weekday bonanza offer", "Women's ddd", "Home fashion sae", "Women fff", "Fashion fiesta offer", "Fashion", "Weekday", "Fashion fies", "Local", "Home le", "Weekdayfff", "Women jena", "Week off", "Women's jewlly", "Brand Launch", "Local brand", "Fashion bazaa", "Women gadf", "Weekend look", "Home fashion avtar", "Weekend ohhh", "Week log", "Local phinomy", "Weekend dhamaka", "Fashionghanae", "Weekday dhamaka", "Womejnfv", "Brandrr Sale", "Demo", "defe", "Otherc", "c3"],
        title: null
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0,0,100],[0,1,"11.07"],[0,2,"8.33"],[0,3,"13.38"],[0,4,"23.56"],[0,5,"17.28"],[0,6,"12.92"],[0,7,"13.54"],[0,8,"26.97"],[0,9,"10.46"],[0,10,"7.72"],[0,11,"9.33"],[0,12,"46.18"],[0,13,"7.27"],[0,14,"34.16"],[0,15,"44.15"],[0,16,100],[0,17,"23.33"],[0,18,"11.55"],[0,19,"9.39"],[0,20,"34.58"],[0,21,"13.97"],[0,22,100],[0,23,"29.96"],[0,24,100],[0,25,100],[0,26,"9.56"],[0,27,100],[0,28,"19.1"],[0,29,"17.42"],[0,30,"13.84"],[0,31,"8.15"],[0,32,"15.37"],[0,33,"10.12"],[0,34,"21.1"],[0,35,"6.9"],[1,0,"11.07"],[1,1,100],[1,2,"42.18"],[1,3,100],[1,4,"28.77"],[1,5,"37.34"],[1,6,"45.63"],[1,7,"44.29"],[1,8,"25.22"],[1,9,"48.41"],[1,10,"40.19"],[1,11,"45.24"],[1,12,"12.67"],[1,13,"38.62"],[1,14,"19.35"],[1,15,"13.61"],[1,16,"33.03"],[1,17,"3.65"],[1,18,100],[1,19,"45.43"],[1,20,"6.17"],[1,21,"43.4"],[1,22,"2.53"],[1,23,"22.55"],[1,24,"25.25"],[1,25,"47.02"],[1,26,"45.91"],[1,27,"22.89"],[1,28,"34.52"],[1,29,"37.11"],[1,30,"43.66"],[1,31,100],[1,32,"40.67"],[1,33,"47.5"],[1,34,"31.77"],[1,35,"37.32"],[2,0,"8.33"],[2,1,"42.18"],[2,2,100],[2,3,"37.02"],[2,4,"22.76"],[2,5,100],[2,6,"37.97"],[2,7,100],[2,8,"19.74"],[2,9,"43.74"],[2,10,"47.95"],[2,11,"46.89"],[2,12,"9.57"],[2,13,"46.31"],[2,14,"14.89"],[2,15,100],[2,16,"26.46"],[2,17,100],[2,18,"41.02"],[2,19,"46.7"],[2,20,"4.58"],[2,21,100],[2,22,"1.86"],[2,23,"17.52"],[2,24,"19.77"],[2,25,"39.3"],[2,26,"46.22"],[2,27,"17.8"],[2,28,"27.78"],[2,29,"30.09"],[2,30,100],[2,31,"49.42"],[2,32,"33.33"],[2,33,"44.64"],[2,34,"25.36"],[2,35,"44.94"],[3,0,"13.38"],[3,1,100],[3,2,"37.02"],[3,3,100],[3,4,"33.38"],[3,5,"42.51"],[3,6,"48.99"],[3,7,"49.66"],[3,8,"29.5"],[3,9,"43.06"],[3,10,"35.13"],[3,11,"39.97"],[3,12,"15.26"],[3,13,"33.65"],[3,14,"22.94"],[3,15,"16.35"],[3,16,"37.96"],[3,17,"4.49"],[3,18,100],[3,19,"40.15"],[3,20,"7.55"],[3,21,"48.75"],[3,22,"3.12"],[3,23,"26.53"],[3,24,"29.54"],[3,25,"47.59"],[3,26,"40.62"],[3,27,"26.92"],[3,28,"39.55"],[3,29,"42.27"],[3,30,"49.02"],[3,31,100],[3,32,"45.96"],[3,33,"42.17"],[3,34,"36.62"],[3,35,"32.43"],[4,0,"23.56"],[4,1,"28.77"],[4,2,"22.76"],[4,3,"33.38"],[4,4,100],[4,5,"40.39"],[4,6,"32.49"],[4,7,"33.68"],[4,8,"45.5"],[4,9,"27.48"],[4,10,100],[4,11,"25.02"],[4,12,"26.43"],[4,13,"20.26"],[4,14,100],[4,15,"28.06"],[4,16,"45.02"],[4,17,"8.58"],[4,18,"29.75"],[4,19,"25.16"],[4,20,"14.01"],[4,21,"34.5"],[4,22,"6.03"],[4,23,"41.89"],[4,24,"45.55"],[4,25,"31.27"],[4,26,"25.53"],[4,27,"42.36"],[4,28,"43.37"],[4,29,100],[4,30,"34.26"],[4,31,"22.35"],[4,32,"37.08"],[4,33,"26.76"],[4,34,"46.45"],[4,35,"19.39"],[5,0,"17.28"],[5,1,"37.34"],[5,2,100],[5,3,"42.51"],[5,4,"40.39"],[5,5,100],[5,6,"41.53"],[5,7,100],[5,8,"36.13"],[5,9,"35.87"],[5,10,"28.6"],[5,11,"32.99"],[5,12,"19.58"],[5,13,"27.27"],[5,14,"28.7"],[5,15,100],[5,16,"45.28"],[5,17,100],[5,18,"38.46"],[5,19,"33.16"],[5,20,"9.94"],[5,21,100],[5,22,"4.17"],[5,23,"32.82"],[5,24,"36.18"],[5,25,"40.17"],[5,26,"33.59"],[5,27,"33.25"],[5,28,"46.94"],[5,29,"49.76"],[5,30,100],[5,31,"29.81"],[5,32,"46.51"],[5,33,"35.03"],[5,34,"43.86"],[5,35,"26.19"],[6,0,"12.92"],[6,1,"45.63"],[6,2,"37.97"],[6,3,"48.99"],[6,4,"32.49"],[6,5,"41.53"],[6,6,100],[6,7,"48.65"],[6,8,"28.66"],[6,9,"44.06"],[6,10,"36.06"],[6,11,"40.94"],[6,12,"14.74"],[6,13,100],[6,14,"22.23"],[6,15,"15.8"],[6,16,"37.01"],[6,17,"4.32"],[6,18,"46.81"],[6,19,"41.13"],[6,20,"7.27"],[6,21,"47.74"],[6,22,"3"],[6,23,100],[6,24,"28.7"],[6,25,"48.6"],[6,26,"41.6"],[6,27,"26.13"],[6,28,"38.59"],[6,29,"41.29"],[6,30,"48.01"],[6,31,"37.42"],[6,32,"44.96"],[6,33,"43.16"],[6,34,"35.69"],[6,35,"33.32"],[7,0,"13.54"],[7,1,"44.29"],[7,2,100],[7,3,"49.66"],[7,4,"33.68"],[7,5,100],[7,6,"48.65"],[7,7,100],[7,8,"29.78"],[7,9,"42.73"],[7,10,"34.82"],[7,11,"39.64"],[7,12,"15.43"],[7,13,"33.35"],[7,14,"23.18"],[7,15,100],[7,16,"38.28"],[7,17,100],[7,18,"45.47"],[7,19,"39.83"],[7,20,"7.64"],[7,21,100],[7,22,"3.16"],[7,23,"26.8"],[7,24,"29.82"],[7,25,"47.25"],[7,26,"40.29"],[7,27,"27.19"],[7,28,"39.87"],[7,29,"42.6"],[7,30,100],[7,31,"36.17"],[7,32,"46.3"],[7,33,"41.84"],[7,34,"36.94"],[7,35,"32.13"],[8,0,"26.97"],[8,1,"25.22"],[8,2,"19.74"],[8,3,"29.5"],[8,4,"45.5"],[8,5,"36.13"],[8,6,"28.66"],[8,7,"29.78"],[8,8,100],[8,9,100],[8,10,"18.47"],[8,11,100],[8,12,"30.09"],[8,13,"17.5"],[8,14,"41.57"],[8,15,"31.84"],[8,16,"40.61"],[8,17,"10.1"],[8,18,"26.12"],[8,19,"21.92"],[8,20,100],[8,21,"30.54"],[8,22,"7.14"],[8,23,"46.33"],[8,24,"49.95"],[8,25,"27.53"],[8,26,"22.25"],[8,27,"46.82"],[8,28,100],[8,29,"36.36"],[8,30,"30.32"],[8,31,"19.37"],[8,32,"32.97"],[8,33,"23.38"],[8,34,"42"],[8,35,"16.72"],[9,0,"10.46"],[9,1,"48.41"],[9,2,"43.74"],[9,3,"43.06"],[9,4,"27.48"],[9,5,"35.87"],[9,6,"44.06"],[9,7,"42.73"],[9,8,100],[9,9,100],[9,10,"41.73"],[9,11,100],[9,12,"11.99"],[9,13,"40.14"],[9,14,"18.38"],[9,15,"12.88"],[9,16,"31.64"],[9,17,"3.43"],[9,18,"47.22"],[9,19,"47.01"],[9,20,100],[9,21,"41.85"],[9,22,"2.37"],[9,23,"21.46"],[9,24,"24.07"],[9,25,"45.45"],[9,26,"47.49"],[9,27,"21.79"],[9,28,100],[9,29,"35.64"],[9,30,"42.1"],[9,31,"43.16"],[9,32,"39.14"],[9,33,"49.09"],[9,34,"30.41"],[9,35,"38.82"],[10,0,"7.72"],[10,1,"40.19"],[10,2,"47.95"],[10,3,"35.13"],[10,4,100],[10,5,"28.6"],[10,6,"36.06"],[10,7,"34.82"],[10,8,"18.47"],[10,9,"41.73"],[10,10,100],[10,11,"44.86"],[10,12,"8.88"],[10,13,"48.36"],[10,14,100],[10,15,"9.57"],[10,16,"24.89"],[10,17,"2.48"],[10,18,"39.05"],[10,19,"44.67"],[10,20,"4.23"],[10,21,"34"],[10,22,"1.71"],[10,23,"16.36"],[10,24,"18.5"],[10,25,"37.36"],[10,26,"44.19"],[10,27,"16.63"],[10,28,"26.16"],[10,29,100],[10,30,"34.24"],[10,31,"48.53"],[10,32,"31.54"],[10,33,"42.62"],[10,34,"23.83"],[10,35,"46.98"],[11,0,"9.33"],[11,1,"45.24"],[11,2,"46.89"],[11,3,"39.97"],[11,4,"25.02"],[11,5,"32.99"],[11,6,"40.94"],[11,7,"39.64"],[11,8,100],[11,9,100],[11,10,"44.86"],[11,11,100],[11,12,"10.7"],[11,13,"43.24"],[11,14,"16.54"],[11,15,"11.51"],[11,16,"28.95"],[11,17,"3.03"],[11,18,"44.06"],[11,19,"49.81"],[11,20,100],[11,21,"38.78"],[11,22,"2.1"],[11,23,"19.39"],[11,24,"21.82"],[11,25,"42.31"],[11,26,"49.32"],[11,27,"19.69"],[11,28,100],[11,29,"32.78"],[11,30,"39.03"],[11,31,"46.31"],[11,32,"36.15"],[11,33,"47.73"],[11,34,"27.78"],[11,35,"41.89"],[12,0,"46.18"],[12,1,"12.67"],[12,2,"9.57"],[12,3,"15.26"],[12,4,"26.43"],[12,5,"19.58"],[12,6,"14.74"],[12,7,"15.43"],[12,8,"30.09"],[12,9,"11.99"],[12,10,"8.88"],[12,11,"10.7"],[12,12,100],[12,13,"8.37"],[12,14,"37.69"],[12,15,"47.95"],[12,16,"22.74"],[12,17,"20.7"],[12,18,"13.21"],[12,19,100],[12,20,"31.2"],[12,21,"15.91"],[12,22,"15.16"],[12,23,"33.27"],[12,24,"30.05"],[12,25,"14.05"],[12,26,100],[12,27,"32.83"],[12,28,"21.58"],[12,29,"19.73"],[12,30,"15.77"],[12,31,"9.37"],[12,32,"17.47"],[12,33,"11.61"],[12,34,"23.76"],[12,35,"7.95"],[13,0,"7.27"],[13,1,"38.62"],[13,2,"46.31"],[13,3,"33.65"],[13,4,"20.26"],[13,5,"27.27"],[13,6,100],[13,7,"33.35"],[13,8,"17.5"],[13,9,"40.14"],[13,10,"48.36"],[13,11,"43.24"],[13,12,"8.37"],[13,13,100],[13,14,"13.12"],[13,15,"9.02"],[13,16,"23.68"],[13,17,"2.33"],[13,18,"37.5"],[13,19,"43.05"],[13,20,"3.98"],[13,21,"32.55"],[13,22,"1.6"],[13,23,100],[13,24,"17.53"],[13,25,"35.84"],[13,26,"42.57"],[13,27,"15.74"],[13,28,"24.91"],[13,29,"27.08"],[13,30,"32.78"],[13,31,"46.89"],[13,32,"30.14"],[13,33,"41.02"],[13,34,"22.66"],[13,35,"48.62"],[14,0,"34.16"],[14,1,"19.35"],[14,2,"14.89"],[14,3,"22.94"],[14,4,100],[14,5,"28.7"],[14,6,"22.23"],[14,7,"23.18"],[14,8,"41.57"],[14,9,"18.38"],[14,10,100],[14,11,"16.54"],[14,12,"37.69"],[14,13,"13.12"],[14,14,100],[14,15,"39.63"],[14,16,"32.73"],[14,17,"13.64"],[14,18,"20.1"],[14,19,"16.65"],[14,20,"21.52"],[14,21,"23.83"],[14,22,"9.75"],[14,23,"45.18"],[14,24,"41.53"],[14,25,"21.28"],[14,26,"16.92"],[14,27,"44.7"],[14,28,"31.27"],[14,29,100],[14,30,"23.64"],[14,31,"14.6"],[14,32,"25.93"],[14,33,"17.84"],[14,34,"34"],[14,35,"12.5"],[15,0,"44.15"],[15,1,"13.61"],[15,2,100],[15,3,"16.35"],[15,4,"28.06"],[15,5,100],[15,6,"15.8"],[15,7,100],[15,8,"31.84"],[15,9,"12.88"],[15,10,"9.57"],[15,11,"11.51"],[15,12,"47.95"],[15,13,"9.02"],[15,14,"39.63"],[15,15,100],[15,16,"24.21"],[15,17,100],[15,18,"14.18"],[15,19,"11.59"],[15,20,"29.46"],[15,21,100],[15,22,"14.13"],[15,23,"35.11"],[15,24,"31.8"],[15,25,"15.07"],[15,26,"11.79"],[15,27,"34.67"],[15,28,"23"],[15,29,"21.07"],[15,30,100],[15,31,"10.09"],[15,32,"18.69"],[15,33,"12.47"],[15,34,"25.28"],[15,35,"8.58"],[16,0,100],[16,1,"33.03"],[16,2,"26.46"],[16,3,"37.96"],[16,4,"45.02"],[16,5,"45.28"],[16,6,"37.01"],[16,7,"38.28"],[16,8,"40.61"],[16,9,"31.64"],[16,10,"24.89"],[16,11,"28.95"],[16,12,"22.74"],[16,13,"23.68"],[16,14,"32.73"],[16,15,"24.21"],[16,16,100],[16,17,"7.13"],[16,18,"34.09"],[16,19,"29.11"],[16,20,"11.77"],[16,21,"39.14"],[16,22,100],[16,23,"37.12"],[16,24,100],[16,25,100],[16,26,"29.51"],[16,27,100],[16,28,"48.33"],[16,29,"45.52"],[16,30,"38.89"],[16,31,"26"],[16,32,"41.84"],[16,33,"30.85"],[16,34,"48.57"],[16,35,"22.7"],[17,0,"23.33"],[17,1,"3.65"],[17,2,100],[17,3,"4.49"],[17,4,"8.58"],[17,5,100],[17,6,"4.32"],[17,7,100],[17,8,"10.1"],[17,9,"3.43"],[17,10,"2.48"],[17,11,"3.03"],[17,12,"20.7"],[17,13,"2.33"],[17,14,"13.64"],[17,15,100],[17,16,"7.13"],[17,17,100],[17,18,"3.82"],[17,19,"3.06"],[17,20,"36.54"],[17,21,100],[17,22,"40.63"],[17,23,"11.52"],[17,24,"10.08"],[17,25,"4.09"],[17,26,"3.12"],[17,27,"11.32"],[17,28,"6.7"],[17,29,"6.03"],[17,30,100],[17,31,"2.63"],[17,32,"5.24"],[17,33,"3.31"],[17,34,"7.52"],[17,35,"2.21"],[18,0,"11.55"],[18,1,100],[18,2,"41.02"],[18,3,100],[18,4,"29.75"],[18,5,"38.46"],[18,6,"46.81"],[18,7,"45.47"],[18,8,"26.12"],[18,9,"47.22"],[18,10,"39.05"],[18,11,"44.06"],[18,12,"13.21"],[18,13,"37.5"],[18,14,"20.1"],[18,15,"14.18"],[18,16,"34.09"],[18,17,"3.82"],[18,18,100],[18,19,"44.25"],[18,20,"6.46"],[18,21,"44.57"],[18,22,"2.65"],[18,23,"23.39"],[18,24,"26.16"],[18,25,"48.21"],[18,26,"44.73"],[18,27,"23.74"],[18,28,"35.61"],[18,29,"38.23"],[18,30,"44.83"],[18,31,100],[18,32,"41.82"],[18,33,"46.31"],[18,34,"32.81"],[18,35,"36.22"],[19,0,"9.39"],[19,1,"45.43"],[19,2,"46.7"],[19,3,"40.15"],[19,4,"25.16"],[19,5,"33.16"],[19,6,"41.13"],[19,7,"39.83"],[19,8,"21.92"],[19,9,"47.01"],[19,10,"44.67"],[19,11,"49.81"],[19,12,100],[19,13,"43.05"],[19,14,"16.65"],[19,15,"11.59"],[19,16,"29.11"],[19,17,"3.06"],[19,18,"44.25"],[19,19,100],[19,20,"5.19"],[19,21,"38.96"],[19,22,"2.11"],[19,23,"19.51"],[19,24,"21.95"],[19,25,"42.5"],[19,26,100],[19,27,"19.82"],[19,28,"30.5"],[19,29,"32.95"],[19,30,"39.22"],[19,31,"46.12"],[19,32,"36.33"],[19,33,"47.92"],[19,34,"27.94"],[19,35,"41.7"],[20,0,"34.58"],[20,1,"6.17"],[20,2,"4.58"],[20,3,"7.55"],[20,4,"14.01"],[20,5,"9.94"],[20,6,"7.27"],[20,7,"7.64"],[20,8,100],[20,9,100],[20,10,"4.23"],[20,11,100],[20,12,"31.2"],[20,13,"3.98"],[20,14,"21.52"],[20,15,"29.46"],[20,16,"11.77"],[20,17,"36.54"],[20,18,"6.46"],[20,19,"5.19"],[20,20,100],[20,21,"7.9"],[20,22,"28.26"],[20,23,"18.44"],[20,24,"16.3"],[20,25,"6.9"],[20,26,"5.29"],[20,27,"18.14"],[20,28,100],[20,29,"10.03"],[20,30,"7.83"],[20,31,"4.48"],[20,32,"8.76"],[20,33,"5.62"],[20,34,"12.38"],[20,35,"3.77"],[21,0,"13.97"],[21,1,"43.4"],[21,2,100],[21,3,"48.75"],[21,4,"34.5"],[21,5,100],[21,6,"47.74"],[21,7,100],[21,8,"30.54"],[21,9,"41.85"],[21,10,"34"],[21,11,"38.78"],[21,12,"15.91"],[21,13,"32.55"],[21,14,"23.83"],[21,15,100],[21,16,"39.14"],[21,17,100],[21,18,"44.57"],[21,19,"38.96"],[21,20,"7.9"],[21,21,100],[21,22,"3.27"],[21,23,"27.52"],[21,24,"30.59"],[21,25,"46.34"],[21,26,"39.42"],[21,27,"27.91"],[21,28,"40.75"],[21,29,"43.49"],[21,30,100],[21,31,"35.33"],[21,32,"47.2"],[21,33,"40.96"],[21,34,"37.79"],[21,35,"31.35"],[22,0,100],[22,1,"2.53"],[22,2,"1.86"],[22,3,"3.12"],[22,4,"6.03"],[22,5,"4.17"],[22,6,"3"],[22,7,"3.16"],[22,8,"7.14"],[22,9,"2.37"],[22,10,"1.71"],[22,11,"2.1"],[22,12,"15.16"],[22,13,"1.6"],[22,14,"9.75"],[22,15,"14.13"],[22,16,100],[22,17,"40.63"],[22,18,"2.65"],[22,19,"2.11"],[22,20,"28.26"],[22,21,"3.27"],[22,22,100],[22,23,"8.18"],[22,24,100],[22,25,100],[22,26,"2.15"],[22,27,100],[22,28,"4.69"],[22,29,"4.21"],[22,30,"3.24"],[22,31,"1.81"],[22,32,"3.64"],[22,33,"2.29"],[22,34,"5.27"],[22,35,"1.52"],[23,0,"29.96"],[23,1,"22.55"],[23,2,"17.52"],[23,3,"26.53"],[23,4,"41.89"],[23,5,"32.82"],[23,6,100],[23,7,"26.8"],[23,8,"46.33"],[23,9,"21.46"],[23,10,"16.36"],[23,11,"19.39"],[23,12,"33.27"],[23,13,100],[23,14,"45.18"],[23,15,"35.11"],[23,16,"37.12"],[23,17,"11.52"],[23,18,"23.39"],[23,19,"19.51"],[23,20,"18.44"],[23,21,"27.52"],[23,22,"8.18"],[23,23,100],[23,24,"46.28"],[23,25,"24.69"],[23,26,"19.81"],[23,27,"49.51"],[23,28,"35.57"],[23,29,"33.03"],[23,30,"27.31"],[23,31,"17.18"],[23,32,"29.81"],[23,33,"20.85"],[23,34,"38.47"],[23,35,"14.77"],[24,0,100],[24,1,"25.25"],[24,2,"19.77"],[24,3,"29.54"],[24,4,"45.55"],[24,5,"36.18"],[24,6,"28.7"],[24,7,"29.82"],[24,8,"49.95"],[24,9,"24.07"],[24,10,"18.5"],[24,11,"21.82"],[24,12,"30.05"],[24,13,"17.53"],[24,14,"41.53"],[24,15,"31.8"],[24,16,100],[24,17,"10.08"],[24,18,"26.16"],[24,19,"21.95"],[24,20,"16.3"],[24,21,"30.59"],[24,22,100],[24,23,"46.28"],[24,24,100],[24,25,100],[24,26,"22.29"],[24,27,100],[24,28,"39.05"],[24,29,"36.4"],[24,30,"30.36"],[24,31,"19.4"],[24,32,"33.02"],[24,33,"23.41"],[24,34,"42.05"],[24,35,"16.75"],[25,0,100],[25,1,"47.02"],[25,2,"39.3"],[25,3,"47.59"],[25,4,"31.27"],[25,5,"40.17"],[25,6,"48.6"],[25,7,"47.25"],[25,8,"27.53"],[25,9,"45.45"],[25,10,"37.36"],[25,11,"42.31"],[25,12,"14.05"],[25,13,"35.84"],[25,14,"21.28"],[25,15,"15.07"],[25,16,100],[25,17,"4.09"],[25,18,"48.21"],[25,19,"42.5"],[25,20,"6.9"],[25,21,"46.34"],[25,22,100],[25,23,"24.69"],[25,24,100],[25,25,100],[25,26,"42.97"],[25,27,100],[25,28,"37.26"],[25,29,"39.93"],[25,30,"46.61"],[25,31,"38.75"],[25,32,"43.57"],[25,33,"44.54"],[25,34,"34.41"],[25,35,"34.58"],[26,0,"9.56"],[26,1,"45.91"],[26,2,"46.22"],[26,3,"40.62"],[26,4,"25.53"],[26,5,"33.59"],[26,6,"41.6"],[26,7,"40.29"],[26,8,"22.25"],[26,9,"47.49"],[26,10,"44.19"],[26,11,"49.32"],[26,12,100],[26,13,"42.57"],[26,14,"16.92"],[26,15,"11.79"],[26,16,"29.51"],[26,17,"3.12"],[26,18,"44.73"],[26,19,100],[26,20,"5.29"],[26,21,"39.42"],[26,22,"2.15"],[26,23,"19.81"],[26,24,"22.29"],[26,25,"42.97"],[26,26,100],[26,27,"20.13"],[26,28,"30.92"],[26,29,"33.38"],[26,30,"39.68"],[26,31,"45.64"],[26,32,"36.78"],[26,33,"48.4"],[26,34,"28.33"],[26,35,"41.23"],[27,0,100],[27,1,"22.89"],[27,2,"17.8"],[27,3,"26.92"],[27,4,"42.36"],[27,5,"33.25"],[27,6,"26.13"],[27,7,"27.19"],[27,8,"46.82"],[27,9,"21.79"],[27,10,"16.63"],[27,11,"19.69"],[27,12,"32.83"],[27,13,"15.74"],[27,14,"44.7"],[27,15,"34.67"],[27,16,100],[27,17,"11.32"],[27,18,"23.74"],[27,19,"19.82"],[27,20,"18.14"],[27,21,"27.91"],[27,22,100],[27,23,"49.51"],[27,24,100],[27,25,100],[27,26,"20.13"],[27,27,100],[27,28,"36.02"],[27,29,"33.47"],[27,30,"27.7"],[27,31,"17.46"],[27,32,"30.22"],[27,33,"21.17"],[27,34,"38.93"],[27,35,"15.02"],[28,0,"19.1"],[28,1,"34.52"],[28,2,"27.78"],[28,3,"39.55"],[28,4,"43.37"],[28,5,"46.94"],[28,6,"38.59"],[28,7,"39.87"],[28,8,100],[28,9,100],[28,10,"26.16"],[28,11,100],[28,12,"21.58"],[28,13,"24.91"],[28,14,"31.27"],[28,15,"23"],[28,16,"48.33"],[28,17,"6.7"],[28,18,"35.61"],[28,19,"30.5"],[28,20,100],[28,21,"40.75"],[28,22,"4.69"],[28,23,"35.57"],[28,24,"39.05"],[28,25,"37.26"],[28,26,"30.92"],[28,27,"36.02"],[28,28,100],[28,29,"47.18"],[28,30,"40.49"],[28,31,"27.31"],[28,32,"43.48"],[28,33,"32.3"],[28,34,"46.9"],[28,35,"23.9"],[29,0,"17.42"],[29,1,"37.11"],[29,2,"30.09"],[29,3,"42.27"],[29,4,100],[29,5,"49.76"],[29,6,"41.29"],[29,7,"42.6"],[29,8,"36.36"],[29,9,"35.64"],[29,10,100],[29,11,"32.78"],[29,12,"19.73"],[29,13,"27.08"],[29,14,100],[29,15,"21.07"],[29,16,"45.52"],[29,17,"6.03"],[29,18,"38.23"],[29,19,"32.95"],[29,20,"10.03"],[29,21,"43.49"],[29,22,"4.21"],[29,23,"33.03"],[29,24,"36.4"],[29,25,"39.93"],[29,26,"33.38"],[29,27,"33.47"],[29,28,"47.18"],[29,29,100],[29,30,"43.23"],[29,31,"29.61"],[29,32,"46.27"],[29,33,"34.81"],[29,34,"44.1"],[29,35,"26.01"],[30,0,"13.84"],[30,1,"43.66"],[30,2,100],[30,3,"49.02"],[30,4,"34.26"],[30,5,100],[30,6,"48.01"],[30,7,100],[30,8,"30.32"],[30,9,"42.1"],[30,10,"34.24"],[30,11,"39.03"],[30,12,"15.77"],[30,13,"32.78"],[30,14,"23.64"],[30,15,100],[30,16,"38.89"],[30,17,100],[30,18,"44.83"],[30,19,"39.22"],[30,20,"7.83"],[30,21,100],[30,22,"3.24"],[30,23,"27.31"],[30,24,"30.36"],[30,25,"46.61"],[30,26,"39.68"],[30,27,"27.7"],[30,28,"40.49"],[30,29,"43.23"],[30,30,100],[30,31,"35.58"],[30,32,"46.94"],[30,33,"41.22"],[30,34,"37.54"],[30,35,"31.58"],[31,0,"8.15"],[31,1,100],[31,2,"49.42"],[31,3,100],[31,4,"22.35"],[31,5,"29.81"],[31,6,"37.42"],[31,7,"36.17"],[31,8,"19.37"],[31,9,"43.16"],[31,10,"48.53"],[31,11,"46.31"],[31,12,"9.37"],[31,13,"46.89"],[31,14,"14.6"],[31,15,"10.09"],[31,16,"26"],[31,17,"2.63"],[31,18,100],[31,19,"46.12"],[31,20,"4.48"],[31,21,"35.33"],[31,22,"1.81"],[31,23,"17.18"],[31,24,"19.4"],[31,25,"38.75"],[31,26,"45.64"],[31,27,"17.46"],[31,28,"27.31"],[31,29,"29.61"],[31,30,"35.58"],[31,31,100],[31,32,"32.82"],[31,33,"44.06"],[31,34,"24.92"],[31,35,"45.52"],[32,0,"15.37"],[32,1,"40.67"],[32,2,"33.33"],[32,3,"45.96"],[32,4,"37.08"],[32,5,"46.51"],[32,6,"44.96"],[32,7,"46.3"],[32,8,"32.97"],[32,9,"39.14"],[32,10,"31.54"],[32,11,"36.15"],[32,12,"17.47"],[32,13,"30.14"],[32,14,"25.93"],[32,15,"18.69"],[32,16,"41.84"],[32,17,"5.24"],[32,18,"41.82"],[32,19,"36.33"],[32,20,"8.76"],[32,21,"47.2"],[32,22,"3.64"],[32,23,"29.81"],[32,24,"33.02"],[32,25,"43.57"],[32,26,"36.78"],[32,27,"30.22"],[32,28,"43.48"],[32,29,"46.27"],[32,30,"46.94"],[32,31,"32.82"],[32,32,100],[32,33,"38.28"],[32,34,"40.45"],[32,35,"28.99"],[33,0,"10.12"],[33,1,"47.5"],[33,2,"44.64"],[33,3,"42.17"],[33,4,"26.76"],[33,5,"35.03"],[33,6,"43.16"],[33,7,"41.84"],[33,8,"23.38"],[33,9,"49.09"],[33,10,"42.62"],[33,11,"47.73"],[33,12,"11.61"],[33,13,"41.02"],[33,14,"17.84"],[33,15,"12.47"],[33,16,"30.85"],[33,17,"3.31"],[33,18,"46.31"],[33,19,"47.92"],[33,20,"5.62"],[33,21,"40.96"],[33,22,"2.29"],[33,23,"20.85"],[33,24,"23.41"],[33,25,"44.54"],[33,26,"48.4"],[33,27,"21.17"],[33,28,"32.3"],[33,29,"34.81"],[33,30,"41.22"],[33,31,"44.06"],[33,32,"38.28"],[33,33,100],[33,34,"29.64"],[33,35,"39.69"],[34,0,"21.1"],[34,1,"31.77"],[34,2,"25.36"],[34,3,"36.62"],[34,4,"46.45"],[34,5,"43.86"],[34,6,"35.69"],[34,7,"36.94"],[34,8,"42"],[34,9,"30.41"],[34,10,"23.83"],[34,11,"27.78"],[34,12,"23.76"],[34,13,"22.66"],[34,14,"34"],[34,15,"25.28"],[34,16,"48.57"],[34,17,"7.52"],[34,18,"32.81"],[34,19,"27.94"],[34,20,"12.38"],[34,21,"37.79"],[34,22,"5.27"],[34,23,"38.47"],[34,24,"42.05"],[34,25,"34.41"],[34,26,"28.33"],[34,27,"38.93"],[34,28,"46.9"],[34,29,"44.1"],[34,30,"37.54"],[34,31,"24.92"],[34,32,"40.45"],[34,33,"29.64"],[34,34,100],[34,35,"21.71"],[35,0,"6.9"],[35,1,"37.32"],[35,2,"44.94"],[35,3,"32.43"],[35,4,"19.39"],[35,5,"26.19"],[35,6,"33.32"],[35,7,"32.13"],[35,8,"16.72"],[35,9,"38.82"],[35,10,"46.98"],[35,11,"41.89"],[35,12,"7.95"],[35,13,"48.62"],[35,14,"12.5"],[35,15,"8.58"],[35,16,"22.7"],[35,17,"2.21"],[35,18,"36.22"],[35,19,"41.7"],[35,20,"3.77"],[35,21,"31.35"],[35,22,"1.52"],[35,23,"14.77"],[35,24,"16.75"],[35,25,"34.58"],[35,26,"41.23"],[35,27,"15.02"],[35,28,"23.9"],[35,29,"26.01"],[35,30,"31.58"],[35,31,"45.52"],[35,32,"28.99"],[35,33,"39.69"],[35,34,"21.71"],[35,35,100]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 800px; min-width: 510px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify what you are asking. Does the HeatMap work for smaller datasets with the same settings?

Comment: Yes it is working fine for the smaller datasets.

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is caused by `turboThreshold` property. You need to increase it:

```
series: [{
    turboThreshold: 9e9,
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1vxm7eou/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.turboThreshold

Comment: Thank you. The chart is coming properly now. But the labels of `x-axis` and `y-axis` are not showing properly. They are coming like for two cells one label.

Comment: You need to set `step: 1` for the labels. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g19pmyu0/